# Char pointers vs Int pointers passed to functions

Tags: c++, function, pointers, char

I thought I understood pointers, but I think there's a nuance by how they're treated differently that I'm not quite following. When I pass an integer pointer or the address of an integer to showInt, it will print out the same memory address as it would outside the function. However. When I pass the following pointer to showChar;

```
char* value = "One";
showChar(value);
```

The address of the first element is different inside the function than it is outside the function. I understand that this is behaviour consistent with passing by value, and that a copy of the pointer is made within the function, however I was under the impression that a copy of a pointer still held the same address. Why is it different when dealing with pointers to char? If the char pointer just stores the address of the first element of the string literal, then why would the pointer in the function not point to the same memory location, but instead point to a new area in memory? That suggests to me that it isn't copying a char pointer, but creating a new char pointer and assigning it the value pointed to by the original pointer. If so, I don't understand why.

I understand that you can access the pointer address in the function by passing a pointer-to-pointer, or a reference-to-pointer instead, but why this is the case still confuses me.

**Passing a pointer to char;**

```
void showChar(char* name){

 cout << name << endl;
 cout << &name << endl;
}
```

**Passing a pointer to int;**

```
void showInt(int* num){

 cout << num << endl;
 cout << *num << endl;
}
```

Comment: Note that `char* value = "One";` is a deprecated conversion in C++

Comment: `char* name` is on the stack, so when you get the address of it, it is a different address, just as `&num` would give you a different value. I think if you did `cout << (void*) name << endl;` you would get the same value.

Comment: @leemes; I'm aware that there is a difference between char* value = "One", and char value[] = "One". I'm just trying to understand the differences in behaviour, and why pointers to array of chars behave differently.

Comment: @MartynShutt, what leemes was saying is that you should have put `const` before the pointer, since `"One"` can be pointed to by a `const char *`, not a `char *`.

Comment: @Shahba; because I'm initialising the pointer to a string literal?

Comment: and hence the const. You should use const char * when you initialize to a string literal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `showChar` and `showInt` functions are printing different things.

In `showChar`, this:

```
cout << &name << endl;
```

prints the address of `name`, which is a *local variable*.  In `showInt`, you don't print the value of `&num`; rather you print the *value* of `num`, which is an address, but not the address of a local variable.

In `showChar`, if you want to print value of `name` *as an address*, you'll need to convert it to some other pointer type such as `void*`:

```
cout << (void*)name << endl;
```

because the overload of `operator<<` for `char*` dereferences the `char*` pointer and prints the C-style string that it points to.

In more detail:

```
void showChar(char* name){
 cout << name << endl;    // prints the contents of the string that
                          // `name` points to
 cout << &name << endl;   // prints the address of the local variable `name`
}

void showInt(int* num){
 cout << num << endl;     // prints the value of the pointer `num`
 cout << *num << endl;    // prints the value of the `int` object that
                          // `num` points to
}
```

Comment: Ah. So it's not a difference in behaviour, but to do with the way the the << operator is overloaded to handle C-Style strings. I was already aware it did this to print the array. I was just unaware it also behaved differently with addresses as well.

Comment: @MartynShutt: The special behavior applies only to pointers parameters. You *cannot* pass an array as an argument to `operator<<`. An expression of array type, in most contexts, is implicitly converted to a pointer to its first element. (The exceptions to this include `&arr` and `sizeof arr`.) Passing a `char*` to `cout << ...` causes it to assume that the `char*` points to the first character of a C-style string.

Comment: I understand. This is completely in line with what I would expect from the behaviour of pointers. I was beginning to think I'd completely misunderstood their behaviour. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The first line in `showChar`:

```
    cout << name << endl;
```

will print the *contents* behind the pointer `name`, since the IO streams operators in C++ are  overloaded to print char-pointers as text instead of the pointer as a number.

With the second line in this function

```
    cout << &name << endl;
```

you don't print the pointer address `name` but instead the pointer (address) of the local variable `name` (which happens to be of a pointer type). That's taking the reference one time too much. What you want is change the behavior of how `operator<<(ostream &, char*)` works, namely printing the pointer address instead of printing a C-string.

You can do this by simply converting the pointer before passing it to `cout`, like this:

```
void showChar(char* name){
    cout << (void*)name << endl;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I've marked up your answer as this also answers my question. Unfortunately I'm only able to accept one answer, however your answer is also very clear in explaining where I was going wrong.